# Parsing Complex JSON string using VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing

I have a complex JSON as below

```
{
"?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "UTF-8"
},
"env:Envelope": {
    "@xmlns": "http://com/ccccc",
    "@xmlns:env": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "env:Header": {
        "uhtHeader": {
            "@xmlns": "http://com/bbbbbb",
            "consumer": "XXXXX",
            "auditId": "",
            "sendTimestamp": "2020-07-27T13:47:53.172-05:00",
            "environment": "P",
            "businessService": {
                "@version": "16",
                "#text": "Filename"
            },
            "status": "success"
        }
    },
    "env:Body": {
        "srvcRspn": {
            "@xmlns": "http://com/aaaaaaa",
            "srvcErrList": {
                "@arrayType": "srvcErrOccur[2]",
                "@type": "Array",
                "srvcErrOccur": [
                    {
                        "orig": "Foundation",
                        "rtnCd": "00",
                        "explCd": "000",
                        "desc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "orig": "YYYYYYY",
                        "rtnCd": "0000",
                        "explCd": "",
                        "desc": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "icn": "1234567890",
            "icnSufx": "01",
            "adjOfc": "123",
            "fln": "12345678",
            "empId": {
                "id1": "S",
                "ssn": "abcdefghij"
            },
            "engInd": "C",
            "xcob": {
                "ssn1": "",
                "ssn9": "",
                "appl": ""
            },
            "provList": {
                "@arrayType": "provOccur[2]",
                "@type": "Array",
                "provOccur": [
                    {
                        "tin": "123456789012345",
                        "nm": "ABCD EFGH",
                        "typSpec": "MD"
                    },
                    {
                        "tin": "000000000000000",
                        "nm": "",
                        "typSpec": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "newOfc": "000",
            "origOfc": "",
            "drg": "",
            "drgAmt": "00000000000",
            "totChrg": "00000046212",
            "causCd": "4",
            "icdVersionInd": "",
            "procCdList": {
                "@arrayType": "procCdOccur[5]",
                "@type": "Array",
                "procCdOccur": [
                    {
                        "procCd": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "procCd": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "procCd": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "procCd": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "procCd": ""
                    }
                ]
            },                                
            "atdPhysnId": {
                "drNmLst": "ABCD",
                "drNmFst": "EFGH",
                "drNmInit": "L"
            },
            "provAdr": {
                "adr": "1234 ABCD EFGH",
                "adr2": "",
                "cty": "ABCDEFG",
                "st": "AB",
                "zip": "123456789"
            },                
            "attchCdList": {
                "@arrayType": "attchCd[2]",
                "@type": "Array",
                "attchCd": [
                    {
                        "cd": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "occurCdList": {
                "@arrayType": "occurCdOccur[8]",
                "@type": "Array",
                "occurCdOccur": [
                    {
                        "cd": "12345",
                        "dt": "11022020"
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": "1234",
                        "dt": "11022020"
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": "",
                        "dt": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": "",
                        "dt": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": "",
                        "dt": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": "",
                        "dt": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": "",
                        "dt": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cd": "",
                        "dt": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hNr": "",
            "hAdmDiagCd": "",
            "heDiagCd": "",
            "faclRndr": {
                "nm": "",
                "str": "",
                "cty": "",
                "st": "",
                "zip": ""
            },
            "emergInd": "",
            "autoAccInd": "",
            "autoAccSt": "",
            "empRelInd": "",
            "othrDiagList": {
                "@arrayType": "othrDiagOccur[3]",
                "@type": "Array",
                "othrDiagOccur": [
                    {
                        "desc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "desc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "desc": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nbrInsCnt": "1",
            "insList": {
                "@arrayType": "insOccur[1]",
                "@type": "Array",
                "insOccur": {
                    "payrNm": "ABCDEF",
                    "empId": "12345678",
                    "grpId": "",
                    "prrPay": "00000000000"
                }
            },
            "typ1varList": {
                "nbrLnCnt": "2",
                "lnList": {
                    "@arrayType": "lnOccur[2]",
                    "@type": "Array",
                    "lnOccur": [
                        {
                            "plcSrvc": "AB",
                            "frmSrvcDt": "2020-04-21",
                            "toSrvcDt": "2020-04-21",
                            "srvcCd": "123456",
                            "chrgAmt": "00000024200",
                            "cmCd": "",
                            "spltLnInd": "N"
                        },
                        {
                            "plcSrvc": "CD",
                            "frmSrvcDt": "2020-04-21",
                            "toSrvcDt": "2020-04-21",
                            "srvcCd": "AA123",
                            "chrgAmt": "00000005877",
                            "cmCd": "",
                            "spltLnInd": "N"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "authEngTkn": "",
            "adjId": ""
        }
    }
}
```

}

I need to parse this using VB.net in my application and get the values.
I have tried making the below classes using JSONUtils, but getting 4 errors

```
Public Class Xml
    Public Property @version As String
    Public Property @encoding As String
End Class

Public Class BusinessService
    Public Property @version As String
    Public Property #text As String
End Class

Public Class UhtHeader
    Public Property @xmlns As String
    Public Property consumer As String
    Public Property auditId As String
    Public Property sendTimestamp As DateTime
    Public Property environment As String
    Public Property businessService As BusinessService
    Public Property status As String
End Class

Public Class EnvHeader
    Public Property uhtHeader As UhtHeader
End Class

Public Class SrvcErrOccur
    Public Property orig As String
    Public Property rtnCd As String
    Public Property explCd As String
    Public Property desc As String
End Class

Public Class SrvcErrList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property srvcErrOccur As SrvcErrOccur()
End Class

Public Class EmpId
    Public Property id1 As String
    Public Property ssn As String
End Class

Public Class Xcob
    Public Property ssn1 As String
    Public Property ssn9 As String
    Public Property appl As String
End Class

Public Class ProvOccur
    Public Property tin As String
    Public Property nm As String
    Public Property typSpec As String
End Class

Public Class ProvList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property provOccur As ProvOccur()
End Class

Public Class ProcCdOccur
    Public Property procCd As String
End Class

Public Class ProcCdList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property procCdOccur As ProcCdOccur()
End Class

Public Class AtdPhysnId
    Public Property drNmLst As String
    Public Property drNmFst As String
    Public Property drNmInit As String
End Class

Public Class ProvAdr
    Public Property adr As String
    Public Property adr2 As String
    Public Property cty As String
    Public Property st As String
    Public Property zip As String
End Class

Public Class AttchCd
    Public Property cd As String
End Class

Public Class AttchCdList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property attchCd As AttchCd()
End Class

Public Class OccurCdOccur
    Public Property cd As String
    Public Property dt As String
End Class

Public Class OccurCdList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property occurCdOccur As OccurCdOccur()
End Class

Public Class FaclRndr
    Public Property nm As String
    Public Property str As String
    Public Property cty As String
    Public Property st As String
    Public Property zip As String
End Class

Public Class OthrDiagOccur
    Public Property desc As String
End Class

Public Class OthrDiagList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property othrDiagOccur As OthrDiagOccur()
End Class

Public Class InsOccur
    Public Property payrNm As String
    Public Property empId As String
    Public Property grpId As String
    Public Property prrPay As String
End Class

Public Class InsList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property insOccur As InsOccur
End Class

Public Class LnOccur
    Public Property plcSrvc As String
    Public Property frmSrvcDt As String
    Public Property toSrvcDt As String
    Public Property srvcCd As String
    Public Property chrgAmt As String
    Public Property cmCd As String
    Public Property spltLnInd As String
End Class

Public Class LnList
    Public Property @arrayType As String
    Public Property @type As String
    Public Property lnOccur As LnOccur()
End Class

Public Class Typ1varList
    Public Property nbrLnCnt As String
    Public Property lnList As LnList
End Class

Public Class SrvcRspn
    Public Property @xmlns As String
    Public Property srvcErrList As SrvcErrList
    Public Property icn As String
    Public Property icnSufx As String
    Public Property adjOfc As String
    Public Property fln As String
    Public Property empId As EmpId
    Public Property engInd As String
    Public Property xcob As Xcob
    Public Property provList As ProvList
    Public Property newOfc As String
    Public Property origOfc As String
    Public Property drg As String
    Public Property drgAmt As String
    Public Property totChrg As String
    Public Property causCd As String
    Public Property icdVersionInd As String
    Public Property procCdList As ProcCdList
    Public Property atdPhysnId As AtdPhysnId
    Public Property provAdr As ProvAdr
    Public Property attchCdList As AttchCdList
    Public Property occurCdList As OccurCdList
    Public Property hNr As String
    Public Property hAdmDiagCd As String
    Public Property heDiagCd As String
    Public Property faclRndr As FaclRndr
    Public Property emergInd As String
    Public Property autoAccInd As String
    Public Property autoAccSt As String
    Public Property empRelInd As String
    Public Property othrDiagList As OthrDiagList
    Public Property nbrInsCnt As String
    Public Property insList As InsList
    Public Property typ1varList As Typ1varList
    Public Property authEngTkn As String
    Public Property adjId As String
End Class

Public Class EnvBody
    Public Property srvcRspn As SrvcRspn
End Class

Public Class EnvEnvelope
    Public Property @xmlns As String
    Public Property @xmlns:env As String
    Public Property env:Header As EnvHeader
    Public Property env:Body As EnvBody
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property ?xml As Xml
    Public Property env:Envelope As EnvEnvelope
End Class
```

The errors are listed below:

'Public Property  As String' and 'Public Property  As Object' cannot overload each other because they differ only by return types. generating for the lines like

```
Public Property @xmlns As String
```

'Public Property  As String' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.' generating for the lines like

```
Public Property @version As String
```

'Declaration expected.' generating for the lines like

```
Public Property env:Header As EnvHeader
```

'Identifier expected.' generating for the lines like

```
Public Property @type As String
```

I am very much new in this concept and have very small idea about how to parse JSON using VB.Net.

Any help is much appreciated as I have been assigned this project suddenly with a very tight client deliverable timeline. Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course you cannot have properties named `env:Envelope` or `?xml`. Use a `<JsonProperty("[Json Name]")>` to set a proper name to a property. E.g., `<JsonProperty("env:Envelope")> Public Property Envelope As EnvEnvelope`

Comment: Thank you @Jimi for your help. It worked properly. Just to know, can this be done with xml using LINQ? because in my application, the actual response is in xml, I converted it to JSON to parse. Will XML parsing with LINQ be faster?